# Parse Cloud Code Error 141 success/error was not called

Tags: asynchronous, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When the following code is executed, I get "Error: 141 success/error was not called", but I clearly return a success if a "round" is properly retrieved from a user's answer history.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("analyzeRound", function(request, response) {

  var x = [];
  var user = request.user;

  user.get("answerHistory").get("round", {
    success: function(educationRound) {
      for (var i = 0; i < educationRound.length; i++) {
        x.push(0);
      }
      response.success("success");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("failed");
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is `answerHistory` ? Is this a pointer to another object ??

Comment: Yes it is, is that a problem?

Comment: yes, you cannot access an object a pointer points to unless you fetch it

Comment: Ok I may be misunderstanding, but in the parse documentation it says to use `fetch` when trying to refresh an object you already have, but you are saying I don't have the object right? So is there another way I should use `fetch`, or do you mean create a new query?

Comment: I meant you need to load the object first. There is a method called `fetch` which you can use to update an object properties with what's on the server. What is the `round` filed ? Is it an array ?

Comment: Oh ok, ya I fixed the error, thanks so much!! I will post the answer code that is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up giving me what I was looking for, thanks Mo Nazemi!

```
Parse.Cloud.define("analyzeRound", function(request, response) {

  var x = [];
  var user = request.user;

  var answerHistory = user.get("answerHistory");
  answerHistory.fetch({
    success: function(answerHistory) {
      var round = answerHistory.get("round");
      for (var i = 0; i < round.length; i++) {
        x.push(0);
      }
      response.success("success");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("failed");
    }
  });
});
```